# Обращение и взаимодействие с TITLE

Tags: javascript, html, css

Уважаемые знатоки и практикующие! Подскажите, возможно реализовать прокрутку наверх страницы по нажатию на head.TITLE, как это реализовано в некоторых браузерах. Например, в Яндекс.браузере, где на любой странице я могу нажать на вкладку(TITLE) и подняться, а в хроме нет. На прямую я пробовал обратиться и навесить обработчик событий, однако это не дало никакого результата. В каком направлении следует углубиться и о чем почитать. Буду признателен за указание нужного направления.

Comment: Непонятно, что имеется ввиду под `нажатию на head.TITLE`, это нажатие на вкладку? Почитайте про событие `visibilitychange` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

Comment: Да, я в примере с Я.Браузером так и описал, при нажатии на вкладку. Спасибо.